# "TypeError: descriptor 'index' requires a 'list' object but received a 'str'"

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

Recently, as a part of one of my projects i tried to make a text converter from regular to hexadecimal.

```
listA = input()

def letter_swap(to_find,to_swap):
    if i == to_find:
        num = list.index(to_find)
        int(num)
        listA[num] = to_swap

print(listA)
listA = list(listA)
print(listA)
for i in listA:
    letter_swap("a", "61")

listA = str(listA)
print(listA)
```

I wanted it to first get the string, convert it to a list, and in function get index of specific characters and change them (by their indexes) to choosed one (to_swap). And then just print the outcome text. However i get the following error.

```
TypeError: descriptor 'index' requires a 'list' object but received a 
'str').
```

Comment: There's more than one thing wrong with your code, so what's your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can use string expressions like `join()`, `split()`, and `replace()` to convert to a string, manipulate it then convert it back to a list. You should work on your input formatting though. This is the code:

```
listA = list(input('Insert list:'))


def letter_swap(to_find, to_swap):
    manipulated_string = "-".join(listA).replace(to_find, to_swap)
    return manipulated_string.split('-')


print(listA, letter_swap("a", "61"))
```

Output:

> Insert list:abcd
>
> ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] ['61', 'b', 'c', 'd']